# Getting a character at a time with loop_in_C

Tags: c, for-loop, getchar, putchar

I was reading the C Language book and i stuck on following code... As i have shown the C codes i am using the for() loop to get the char in.and same way i use for loop to print a char on screen...if the users presses the enter the loop will quit, and the other for() loop which is used to print on the screen will use the value of i variable. But the result on screen is reversed. Can i  get your opinion how can i sort it out?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int i;
char msg[25];
printf_s("Type up to 25 characters then press Enter..\n");
for (i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
    msg[i] = getchar();// Gets a character at a time
    if (msg[i] == '\n'){
        i--;
        break;// quits if users presses the Enter
    }
}putchar('\n');
for (; i >= 0 ; i--)
{
    putchar(msg[i]);// Prints a character at a time 

}putchar('\n');/*There is something wrong because it revers the input */

getchar();
return 0;
```

Comment: Im not that familiar with C but I can tell you right now the for loop your using is decrementing not incrementing, which may explain why it is printing the characters in reverse order... What are you expecting to do with your second for-loop as far as printing results?

Comment: If i would use the increment operator it will do to infinite loop....and it will cause buffer overflow

Comment: Right but the for-loop is doing exactly what you told it to do, print characters in reverse order. What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: Yes i know, but i want  to print it on regular way. I am asking if there is any way to sort it out and print as the user wrote

Comment: Can you update your question and provide an example of what you are expecting to do in this second for-loop?

Comment: First for loop will just get the input into variable msg[i]
Second for loop will print the output from variable msg[i]

Comment: Ok so quite possibly, you may just need to switch the equality operators around in the second for loop

Comment: You mean
 for (; i <= 0 ; i++)
 {
  putchar(msg[i]);// Prints a character at a time 

 }putchar('\n');

Comment: use `qsort` for sort.

Comment: Thanks, this might be one of the solutions...

Comment: the posted code will have a problem on windows/dos systems (where a newline is actually 2 characters.  Also getchar() actually returns an int, not a char.  suggest reading into an int, then assigning to the char array after checking if input is a newline.

Comment: @user3629249 This should only be a problem on Windows where `stdin` is opened in binary mode (`_O_BINARY`) rather than text mode (`_O_TEXT`).  In the case of the OP, that isn't true as `stdin` is in text mode by default, so newline translation is in effect for both input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the input, the variable `i` holds the exact number of characters in `msg`. That's why there is a `i--` statement, so that when you enter `ab<enter>` you'll have i==2 not i==3.

The second loop counts backwards to 0, which isn't what you want. You'll want to count from 0 up to `i` instead. Now you can't count up to i using i. You need two variables: one to keep the maximum, and one to do the actual counting.

I'll leave it up to you to decide how to do it exactly, because that's part of the learning.

Comment: Thank you for your reply... Since the user enters ab<enter> and the variable i will be =2, I create one more variable with name a. But it seems that its not the solution, or i understood you wrong 
        int a;
 for (a=0; a < msg[i] ; a++)
 {
  putchar(msg[i]);// Prints a character at a time 

 }

Comment: @FatlonderCakolli: Almost there: it has to be `a < i` - you have to compare the two numbers. You now compare the number `a` with the character `msg[i]`, and we know that is `\n` <Enter>.

Comment: sorry for late reply i solve it thank you for advice
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
 int i;
 char msg[25];
 printf_s("Type up to 25 characters then press Enter..\n");
 for (i = 0; i < 25; i++)
 {
  msg[i] = getchar();// Gets a character at a time
  if (msg[i] == '\n'){
   i--;
   break;// quits if users presses the Enter
  }
 }putchar('\n');

 int a;
 for (a=0; a <=i; a++)
{ 
putchar(msg[a]); 
}putchar('\n');
 return 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

To sort by using the `qsort` is written as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cmp(const void *, const void *);

int main(void){
    int i, n;
    char msg[25];

    printf_s("Type up to 25 characters then press Enter..\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++){
        int ch = getchar();
        if(ch == '\n' || ch == EOF)
            break;//if (msg[i] == '\n'){i--; <<- this cannot be 25 character input.
        else
            msg[i] = ch;
    }
    putchar('\n');

    n = i;
    qsort(msg, n, sizeof(char), cmp);//sizeof(char) : 1

    for (i = 0; i < n ; ++i){
        putchar(msg[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');

    getchar();
    return 0;
}

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b){
    unsigned char x = *(const char *)a;
    unsigned char y = *(const char *)b;
    return (x < y) ? -1 : (x > y);//Ascending order
}
```